# Stacked tables will not start on new row

Tags: html, css, html-email

I am currently working on mobilizing an email template for work. The desktop version should display an image on the left and text on the right within a table. This renders fine until I tried to add an additional table. It will not start on a new line and instead, the image starts on the right hand side with the text on the next line.

Here is the sample HTML:

```
<body>
<tr>
<td class="innerpadding">
<table width="200" align="left" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">  
<tr>
<td height="200" style="padding: 0 10px 10px 0;">
<img src="images/article1.png" width="200" height="200" border="0" alt="" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
 <table width="380" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
 <tr>
<td>
<![endif]-->
<table class="col380" align="left" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%; max-width: 600px;" >  
<tr>
<td>
<table width="95%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In tempus adipiscing felis, sit amet blandit ipsum volutpat sed. Morbi porttitor, eget accumsan dictum, nisi libero ultricies ipsum, in posuere mauris neque at erat. 
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
<!--This is where the next row and table begin-->
<tr>
<td class="innerpadding">
<table width="200" align="left" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">  
<tr>
<td height="200" style="padding: 0 10px 10px 0;">
<img src="images/article1.png" width="200" height="200" border="0" alt=""/>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
<table width="380" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr>
<td>
<![endif]-->
<table class="col380" align="left" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%; max-width: 600px;">  
<tr>
<td>
<table width="95%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In tempus adipiscing felis, sit amet blandit ipsum volutpat sed. Morbi porttitor, eget accumsan dictum, nisi libero ultricies ipsum, in posuere mauris neque at erat.
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<![endif]-->
</td>
</tr>
</body>
```

I previously tried to use  around the entire body, which fixed the issue, but undid the media queries that I created. Here is the inline style code that I'm using. I have been trying to apply an inline-block to the row, but it doesn't seem to render any render any differently:

```
tr {
display:inline-block
}
.innerpadding {padding: 0px 100px 0px 0px;}
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 400px) {
.col380 {width: 380px !important;}

}
```

Comment: Your code is semantically and syntactically broken. Please read up on how to proprly use HTML tables.

Comment: @Hubert Thanks for the advice. Not sure how it's helpful or constructive, but great feedback for a beginner. :)

Comment: To elaborate on it: tables consist of rows (tr) and rows contain cells (td). In your markup you have rows that lie outside all tables. Also you're using a whole table and even nested tables to wrap single elements, instead of putting all elements into one table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this adding float left into the innerpadding class. 
Also fix the your end tags you appear to be missing some. Additionally, not sure if you would want to use  and  when  works perfectly. So I changed the beginning  and  to  and 
    This is what worked for me:

```
.innerpadding {
    padding: 0px 100px 0px 0px;
    float: left
}





<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <style>
        tr {
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .innerpadding {
            padding: 0px 100px 0px 0px;
            float: left
        }

        {
            table:;
        }
    </style>
    <title>Something</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="innerpadding">
<table width="200" align="left" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">  
  <tr>
    <td height="200" style="padding: 0 10px 10px 0;">
      <img src="images/article1.png" width="200" height="200" border="0" alt="" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
  <table width="380" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td>
<![endif]-->
<table class="col380" align="left" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%; max-width: 600px;" >  
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table width="95%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
          <td>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In tempus adipiscing felis, sit amet blandit ipsum volutpat sed. Morbi porttitor, eget accumsan dictum, nisi libero ultricies ipsum, in posuere mauris neque at erat. 
        </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
<!--This is where the next row and table begin-->
<div class="innerpadding">
<table width="200" align="left" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">  
  <tr>
    <td height="200" style="padding: 0 10px 10px 0;">
      <img src="images/article1.png" width="200" height="200" border="0" alt="" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
  <table width="380" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td>
<![endif]-->
<table class="col380" align="left" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%; max-width: 600px;" >  
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table width="95%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
          <td>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In tempus adipiscing felis, sit amet blandit ipsum volutpat sed. Morbi porttitor, eget accumsan dictum, nisi libero ultricies ipsum, in posuere mauris neque at erat. 
        </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<script>


</script>
</html>
```

References: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp

Comment: thanks for the help. Although the code did help the information start on a new line, it undid the media queries I set up for the mobile portion. Currently fiddling around to try and make up for it.

Comment: Duh I just had to add them back in. -_- Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yeah no problem, best of luck on your project.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've taken the "use tables in emails" a bit wrong. The point is not wrapping every single element inside a table, but to make the whole email one big table. Some email clients are from the last century when it comes to properly render CSS based layout. There is the only reason to use tables (except you really want tables): layout. With tables you tell what goes where on the page by putting your elements inside table cells. This way you can have layout without any CSS.

In case you insist on useless, bloated boilerplate code: try a `<br>` between the tables. `<br>` means "break line".

Comment: I understand what you're saying. I am using the table as a way to layout the images and texts within the email because of the structure already in place for them. Through trial and error, this seems to be the easiest way to change the media queries. I just can't figure out how to multiply what I have for the first table (the layout and format that works) again so that I can add additional text and images to the email.

Comment: This is certainly not the easiest way to do anything with media queries. In fact, ths has nothing to do with media queries.